# like search on number column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I do a `like` search on a number column in SQL?

I want numbers which are `like '0.0000%'`.

I tried with

```
select * from emp where emp_id & '' like '123%'
select * from emp where CONVERT(varchar(20), emp_id) like '123%'
```

but in vain.

Please help me

Comment: Using `LIKE` on a number doesn't make sense.

Comment: '%' is a wildcard character which means sort of "anything", e.g. '123%' means "starts with 123, then any string (even null)". In order to use a wildcard character as a literal character, enclose the wildcard character in brackets. So your LIKE above should be '0.0000[%]' to find this ("0.0000%") exact format

Comment: This question seems to suffer from an acute lack of focus. **(1)** It is (currently) tagged as [tag:ms-access], yet the question refers to `CONVERT()`, which Access SQL does not support. **(2)** As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, the essence of the question (using `LIKE` on a number) is suspect. **(3)** Finally, there is confusion over the role of `%` as a wildcard, or as numeric shorthand. **user1912935:** Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16186962/edit) your question to clarify your SQL environment and provide some examples of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @GordThompson: I changed the tag from `oracle` to `ms-access` because of the `emp_id & ''` expression - which is the concatenation for MS Access if I'm not mistaken. I assumed that `convert()` - being an "Microsoft" thing - would be available in Access as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for clarifying. I won't change the tag back to [tag:oracle] if it's that unclear as to what "SQL world" we're talking about here.

Comment: @GordThompson: it's most definitely **not** Oracle (`convert` and the `&` operator for concatenation are invalid there). I'm pretty sure it's something in the Microsoft world.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I've changed the tags back. for all we know this is some TSQL they found on the web so unsurprising that it doesn't work in Oracle. The answer they posted references `dual` which is not present in the MS world.

Comment: @MartinSmith: guess you are right.

Answer (score 10):

Regardless of which DBMS you are using AND assuming you have a valid reason to do this, you have several ways to solve problems like these. I can think of three right now:

1. Convert the number to a string and use a LIKE operator on this:

   ```
   select *
   from emp
   where to_char(emp_id) like '123%';
   ```
2. Use mathematical operators directly (like Andrey suggests), for example:

   ```
   select *
   from table
   where num between 0 and 0.0001;
   ```
3. Construct a mathematical expression (actually, this is just another case of method 2), for example:

   ```
   select *
   from table
   where abs(num - round(num, 5)) < 0.00001;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Use comparison operators (> and <):

```
select * from table where num > 0 and num < 0.00001
```

Answer (score 0):

select 0.0001*1000 from dual if it is <1 means the 0.0001 has 3 or more zeros.
so i did like
select * from emp where emp_id*10000<1