# How do I query SQL using LIKE to find integers? (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite, integer

I have successfully queried `strings` dynamically with user input like this:

```
def read_part_of_database(table_column, user_query):
    c_lime.execute("SELECT * FROM lime_database_table WHERE {} LIKE '%{}%'" 
            "ORDER BY time_start".format(table_column, user_query))
    for row in c_lime.fetchall():
        print(row)
```

This enables the user to write both the whole or part of a `string` `query` which is passed as `user_query`. `LIKE '%{}'` enables parts of the `query` being accepted.

However, when `user_query` is passed as an `integer` instead of a `string` the `database` returns nothing. This is true whether the whole or part of the `integer` is passed. I assumed that it had to do with quotations around the `string` which is not present for `integers`. So I tried using `%{}%` instead of `'%{}%'`, but this gave the following error:

```
c_lime.execute("SELECT * FROM lime_database_table WHERE {} LIKE {}% ORDER BY time_start".format(table_column, user_query))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ORDER": syntax error
```

So, my question is, if `user_query` is a number instead of a `string`, how do I `query` it using `LIKE`?

As a side note, I have successfully `queried` `user_query` as an `int` using `= ?` instead. Like this:

```
c_lime.execute("SELECT * FROM lime_database_table WHERE {} = ? ORDER BY" 
"time_start".format(table_column), [user_query])
```

But in this case, the user has to write the whole number.

Comment: Check the answers to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186962/like-search-on-number-column-in-sql. The options are to convert the integer to character or to check if the integer falls in a range.

Comment: Do not use string formatting on SQL queries. It will lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use the [proper way](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). Imaging your user input is `"a"; DELETE * FROM lime_database_table --`

Comment: @Julia (again :P) Thanks! I tried converting to string: `c_lime.execute("SELECT * FROM lime_database_table WHERE {} LIKE '%{}%' ORDER BY time_start".format(table_column, str(user_query)))` But still nothing...

Comment: @KlausD. How would you define a query with `LIKE %x%` using a proper way?